# Was Vespucci born as Amerigo?

Tags: names, americas

In a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_UIpdqpA-Gc), it is stated that Vespucci's original first name was "Alberto". The name by which he is popularly known, "Amerigo", was only assigned to him after reaching the New World. At least, so it is stated.

Is there any evidence for this claim?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci#Family_and_education) states that he shared the name "Amerigo" with his grandfather.

Comment: I'm not particularly convinced that the video is in any way authoritative.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci) mentions *Alberigo* as one of the alternate forms of his name, which is also what the YouTube-poster is actually saying, at about four and a quarter minutes into the video. Also, it would appear, from the [same article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerigo_Vespucci#Voyages), that many scholars doubt his alleged travels actually taking place. Just like Jaco*b*us becomes Ja*m*es or Giaco*m*o, in the same manner Al*b*erigo becomes A*m*erigo, both B and M being [labial consonants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labial_consonant).